# Netstat command output description

Tags: linux, port, netstat

In my project i'm checking for the ports availability during server startup. When server is in stop state all ports are showing available(using netstat command-nothing is returning) except the postgres port(5432) on linux. Same port is showing correct status in windows. Following is the netstat output for the 5432 port on linux when the server is not running. I'm wondering can someone please explain what exactly the output mean and why the same it is not showing in windows.

$ netstat -aon | grep "5432"

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36524         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.23/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36518         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (1.85/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36526         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (28.95/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36522         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (21.85/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36523         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.18/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36528         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.48/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36529         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.53/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36527         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (29.00/0/0)

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36520         127.0.0.1:5432          TIME_WAIT   timewait (11.85/0/0)

For all other ports netstat command output is empty when server is not running state. If possible please explain what each column is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just run netstat without grep and you will see column names:

Proto | Recv-Q | Send-Q | Local Address | Foreign Address | State | Timer